# Tooltip in string - Svelte

Tags: html, string, class, tooltip, svelte

Is it possible to pass the tooltip into a string of some variable in Svelte? I know that svelte has {@html expression} which works fine for basics like strong, h1 ... but is there any way how to pass some class with tooltip into the text of a string.

Here is an example:

```
<script>

let description = 'some text where I need to pass the tooltip. Is it possible?';
    
</script>

{description}
```

Comment: You will have to expand a bit on your problem, even code that does not work but you think would is good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like commented your question is a bit vague - but I guess you want to define a tooltip via a variable? Then this is how you could do this [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/21476de095d04ff8935b42de4bb5e6e3?version=3.46.4)

```
<script>
    import Comp from './Comp.svelte'

    let htmlStringWithTooltip = `
    <style>
    [data-tooltip] {
        position: relative;
    }
    [data-tooltip]:hover::before {
        content: attr(data-tooltip);
        position: absolute;
        left: 50%;
        transform: translate(-50%, -100%);
    }
    </style>
    <span data-tooltip='The tooltip'>Hello</span>
    `
</script>

<Comp {htmlStringWithTooltip} />

<style>

    :global(body) {
        padding-top: 3rem;  
    }

</style>
```

###### Comp.svelte

```
<script>

    export let htmlStringWithTooltip = ""

</script>

{@html htmlStringWithTooltip}
```

Comment: Thank you but no. I can't add HTML to that component. I need text+tooltip in that variable together.  If you take that example above. Is it possible to add a tooltip with words HEYY for the text 'I need to pass' ?

Comment: @TomcazBrodku So you want to give a string a tooltip without html & css? I don't think that's possible

Comment: @TomcazBrodku you could do it by passing the html in the string and render it with `{@ html}` and define the needed css globally, but without that I see no way

Comment: I have tried that but that HTML seems to work only for basics like strong, sup, h1 ... but not with the classes or I didn't figure it out yet.

Comment: @TomcazBrodku I modified my answer and the Repl with passing the html string. You can actually include a `<style>` tag in the string with the needed css declarations for the tooltip